# Range annotation failing for Int32 max in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rangevalidator

Following is how range validator is configured in one of my MVC model.

```
[Display(Name = "Event ID")]
[Range(0, 2147483647)]
[Required(ErrorMessage="Event ID must be entered")]
public int? ID_EVENTO { get; set; }
```

While trying to input "32167", it gives me an error message saying "Event ID can be maximum of 2147483647. It is accepting only few 4 digit values.

Any idea of what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, in your Model, `ID_EVENTO` is `System.Int16` in place of `System.Int32` (that is, if you are using SQL Server, the field is `smallint` in place of `int`).